# Recursive induction proof

Tags: proof-verification, induction, recursion, recursive-algorithms

$$() = (−1)+\frac{−1}{^2}⋅\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t(k)$$

Use induction to prove that $()≤2$ for all $≥1$.

I have the base case.

I got \begin{align} (m+1) & = m+\frac{m}{(m+1)^2}⋅\sum_{k=1}^{m}t(k) \\
& \le m+\frac{m}{(m+1)^2}⋅\sum_{k=1}^{m}2k \\
& = m+\frac{m}{(m+1)^2}⋅m(m+1) \\
& = m+\frac{m^2}{(m+1)} \\
& \le 2m+2 \end{align}

Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: How did you get the last inequality?

Comment: @5xum The second term is always less than $m$, as $\frac{m^2}{m+1} = m \cdot \frac{m}{m+1} < m$

Comment: Then yes, your proof is OK.